# Badge icons (especially gold) have a vertical offset

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, badges

I noticed that the icons for users with gold + silver + bronze badges are offset vertically from each other. For example:

[image: badge offset example]

It's difficult to tell if the silver and bronze badges are level (is silver slightly lower than bronze?), but gold is definitely lower than silver and bronze. It appears this way on the [sprites image](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/security/img/sprites.svg?v=71e0d782aa47) as well:

[image: sprites image]

The bug appears on both main and meta.

Comment: Can confirm, how annoying.

Comment: How weird. I never noticed this before, but now cannot unseen it on every page! Wonder if something changed...

Comment: Thanks for reporting. I'm on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks again for reporting this issue. Fix is now waiting in repo for build, so it should be live within next couple hours.