# Sprites not showing up any more

Tags: bug, status-completed

This may be related to [Badge icons (especially gold) have a vertical offset](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2766/badge-icons-especially-gold-have-a-vertical-offset) considering it's about the sprites...

But for some reason I am unable to see any of the sprites on both security.meta.stackexchange.com and security.stackexchange.com.

Is this the same for anyone else?

I've tried disabling my adblockers, switching browsers, disabling cache, etc.

[image: Here's a screenshot of the other linked question in my browser (Firefox)]

Comment: I posted the same issue here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300189/missing-icons-on-security-stackexchange-com#300189, not sure which place is more appropriate.

Comment: Oh good, its not just me. I think both places are probably equally appropriate and will get more attention this way anyway.

Comment: It just started happening to me this afternoon. There was a network event, so maybe it's a caching issue: https://twitter.com/StackStatus

Comment: I'd upvote this post, but I can't find the buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry about that.

A bad image snuck into the deploy, causing this issue.

Comment: Ahhh. The fact that I can upvote and accept your answer is proof that you've fixed it already.